# How aggs by id and order result by title? Elasticsearch 5.5

Tags: elasticsearch

I started to learn Elasticsearch and faced the problem of sorting the grouped results.

I tried to find something about this in the documentation, but I did not find anything.

That's what I have:

Mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "post": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Posts:

```
{
  "title": "some title",
  "message": "some message",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "some tag title"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "some tag title 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "some tag title 3"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "title": "some title 2",
  "message": "some message 2",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "some tag title 2"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "title": "some title 3",
  "message": "some message 3",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "some tag title"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "some tag title 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

My request:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tags": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tags.id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "titles": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": {
                  "include": [
                    "tags.title"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [

    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_tags": {
      "doc_count": 6,
      "tags": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": 2,
            "doc_count": 3,
            "titles": {
              "hits": {
                "total": 3,
                "max_score": 1,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "tags",
                      "offset": 0
                    },
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                      "tags": {
                        "title": "some tag title 2"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 1,
            "doc_count": 2,
            "titles": {
              "hits": {
                "total": 2,
                "max_score": 1,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "tags",
                      "offset": 0
                    },
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                      "tags": {
                        "title": "some tag title"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 3,
            "doc_count": 1,
            "titles": {
              "hits": {
                "total": 1,
                "max_score": 1,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "tags",
                      "offset": 2
                    },
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                      "tags": {
                        "title": "some tag title 3"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can you see result aggregations sorted by doc_count.

**How can I get result aggregations sorted by tag.title?**

What I want:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [

    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_tags": {
      "doc_count": 6,
      "tags": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": 1,
            "doc_count": 2,
            "titles": {
              "hits": {
                "total": 2,
                "max_score": 1,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "tags",
                      "offset": 0
                    },
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                      "tags": {
                        "title": "some tag title"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 2,
            "doc_count": 3,
            "titles": {
              "hits": {
                "total": 3,
                "max_score": 1,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "tags",
                      "offset": 0
                    },
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                      "tags": {
                        "title": "some tag title 2"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 3,
            "doc_count": 1,
            "titles": {
              "hits": {
                "total": 1,
                "max_score": 1,
                "hits": [
                  {
                    "_nested": {
                      "field": "tags",
                      "offset": 2
                    },
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                      "tags": {
                        "title": "some tag title 3"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Sorry for my english.*

**Updated:**

I update request:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tags": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tags.id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "titles": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tags.title.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Updated 2:**

Request:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tags": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tags.id",
            "order": {
              "titles": "asc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "titles": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tags.title.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this request I get error:

```
"reason": {
  "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
  "reason": "Invalid terms aggregation order path [titles]. Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end."
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to use the content of `top_hits` to order parent aggregations. You'll need to create another `terms` sub-aggregation on the `title` field.

Comment: I modified request, how I can sorting aggs result now?

Comment: Now I get error message. (look Updated 2)